# Cannot load any Portable Class Library projects in VS 2013 solution, when it is opened in VS2015 RC

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

While I am trying to load any Portable `Class Library` (`Universal Windows 8.1 Project`) I see an error `"TargetPlatformIdentifier` `is not supported`. One or more `'Windows'` projects have `<TargetPlatformIdentifier>` not equal to 'Windows'.

Adding `TargetPlatformIdentifier` key don't help. Project looks as the default `PCL` project in `VS2015 RC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing ProjectTypeGuids property in .csproj file to values from VS2015 PCL template ProjectTypeGuids property helps.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error in the final release of visual studio 2015.  I worked around it by

1. removing the visual studio 2013 project.
2. I created a new portable class library in the Visual Studio 2015 directory with the same name as the old library.
3. In windows explorer I copied the source files from the old project into the new project.
4. In visual studio select the project, and click the "Show All Files" button at the top of the solution explorer.
5. Include your source files in your new project.
6. Build

That should do it.